# Converting OBJ to FBX with material

Tags: materials, export, unity, obj

I'm trying to convert OBJ to FBX for my project in Unity.

I downloaded this Link model which comes with an OBJ file and MTL file from: https://www.models-resource.com/gamecube/legendofzeldathewindwaker/model/7795/

I imported the OBJ file to Blender using the **Import > Wavefront (.obj)** option and it shows up like this:

[image]

When I look in the Texture Paint tab in Blender it shows the material file has been added successfully:

[image]

But when I export the model to FBX and import to Unity the material is not there? I am very new with Blender and 3d modelling so I am not sure what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, all I had to do was copy all the associated PNG files to where the exported FBX file was located in my Unity Project

[image]